# Why am I getting the Equatable error: The element type can't be assigned to the list type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, dart-null-safety, equatable

I upgraded Flutter to v 3.3.4 and am trying to fix the null safety issues with my blocs, but have run into a problem with Equatable props. When I make one of the event properties nullable, the equatable get props shows the following error on the **[tour]** prop:
The element type 'Tour?' can't be assigned to the list type 'Object'.

Here is the relevant code:

```
part of 'tour_editor_bloc.dart';

abstract class TourEditorEvent extends Equatable {
  const TourEditorEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class OpenTourEditor extends TourEditorEvent {
  final Tour? tour;

  OpenTourEditor({this.tour});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [tour];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you need to make it a list of Tour objects in order to correct your error.

So List<Tour> get props => [tour];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`props` accepts nullable data, change the abstract class props first and then `OpenTourEditor`

```dart
abstract class TourEditorEvent extends Equatable {
  const TourEditorEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class OpenTourEditor extends TourEditorEvent {
  final Tour? tour;

  OpenTourEditor({this.tour});
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [tour];
}
```